# Finding List Of All Checkin's By User Using TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn

I ve used Tortoise svn for some now and what I cant seem to be able to do is find a list of all checking by a username - Does anyone know if that is possible?

Comment: Are you trying to see which files another user has checked out?

Comment: Yes - All files that a user has made changes to

Comment: How to show history of a specific user in svn?
https://superuser.com/questions/270378/how-to-show-history-of-a-specific-user-in-svn

Comment: How to show history of a specific user in svn?
https://superuser.com/questions/270378/how-to-show-history-of-a-specific-user-in-svn

Answer (score 21):

You can filter by Author in the log window, only showing commits made by that author.

There is a search box in the log window, where you can choose what to search, just choose Author and write the name.

Comment: +1 Ha! I never realized the magnifying glass is a drop-down. Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

> Finding List Of All Checking By User Using TortoiseSVN

I am assuming  you mean "check-in"s.

There is no way to  *filter* commits by author in Tortoise that I know of.

However, you can sort by author in the "log" window.

One tool that can do this is [StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/). See e.g. [this demo.](http://www.statsvn.org/demo/objectlabkit/user_benoitx.html)

Comment: How would the log window work?  Its a big branch with 50 developers and a lot of commits - I am very suprised this is not available in SVN

Comment: @Chloe you'd list all commits, sort by author, and scroll to the author you want... It's not optimal but the only way I know. This is not really a task for the subversion client IMO. There are 3rd party stats tools that can do this

Comment: @Chloe I added a link to a 3rd party product that can do this